# Display all data which are between these dates

Tags: php, sql, laravel

So currently, I am trying to display a list of items which are not between date X and date Y.
Let us assume that book_date_start = 2021-06-15, and bookdate_end = 2021-06-20

This is my current query:

```
$query->select('fac_query')
->from('facility_booking')
->where('book_date_start', '>=', $newstartdate)
->where('book_date_end', '<=', $newenddate);
```

So based on this

```
$newstartdate = 2021-06-13 and $newenddate = 2021-06-19 (Returns 0 records)
$newstartdate = 2021-06-21 and $newenddate = 2021-06-25 (Returns 0 records)
$newstartdate = 2021-06-11 and $newenddate = 2021-06-12 (Returns 0 records)
$newstartdate = 2021-06-13 and $newenddate = 2021-06-25 (Returns 1 records)
$newstartdate = 2021-06-17 and $newenddate = 2021-06-19 (Returns 0 records)
```

So basically as I was writing the above out, I realized that my query is WRONG, and since 2021-06-13 is less than 2021-06-15 (true), and 2021-06-20 is more than 2021-06-25 (true) also, that's why it's returning the record.

My question:
How would I write query if I only want to return the record is the chosen date is between 2021-06-15 to 2021-06-20? (I'm pretty sure I'm overthinking this) but I'm SOO lost. I don't need the full query or answer, I just hope someone can point me in slightly the right direction and I'll be good to go.. Thanks all for reading.

Comment: please look at this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: Thank you! So I've realized I should've just did it using
->whereBetween('book_date_start', [$newstartdate, $newenddate]);

This will allow me to check if the start of the date is between this X and Y date. (And if it is, it will return the record).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the query as below.

```
$start_date = Carbon::parse($newstartdate)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end_date = Carbon::parse($newenddate)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$bookinks = \DB::table('facility_booking')->where([['book_date_start','<=',$start_date],['book_date_end','>=',$end_date]])
              ->orwhereBetween('book_date_start',array($start_date,$end_date))
             ->orWhereBetween('book_date_end',array($start_date,$end_date))->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! This works exactly how I had wanted it to. I think I finally understand it now, my original query only checked if the date is smaller than and larger than. It did not checked for anything in between. (That's why once there's a date in between it messes up). But using your query, not only do you check for larger than and smaller than, but you added another check to see if it is between the two dates too. Holy cow thank you so much for helping me to understand how it is supposed to be written!!